# NSTableView not updating like I think it should

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I have the following code:

```
- (void)updateServerList {

    [crazyStuff reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Hi");

}

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"Numbers have Changed");
    return [serverBrowser.servers count];

}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
                objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                row:(int)row
{
    NSLog(@"Starting updates for table");
    NSNetService* server = [serverBrowser.servers objectAtIndex:row];
    return [server name];

}

- (IBAction)tableViewSelected:(id)sender
{
    //row = [sender selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"the user just clicked on row ");
}
```

This is part of a chat program that I'm trying to expand.  It was designed for the iOS and I'm working to get it to work on my laptop and chat with my iPad.  I know that `updateServerList` is called correctly from my log statement.  I also now that `numberOfRowsInTableView:` is called on startup but not anytime else.  I would like to have my Table (the outlet crazyStuff) updated everytime `updateServerList` is called.  How would I trouble shoot to see if it is or is not?  I am not seeing the data show up in the table that "should" be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it then that at startup, when numberOfRowsInTableView is called, it returns 0? If not, is tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: ever called then?

My first guess would be the "crazyStuff" is, in fact, not connected to anything or connected to something other than the table view you intend. Might want to log the value of crazyStuff in updateServerList.

Comment: I have not seen tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: called.  I'll try and log crazyStuff and see what happens

Comment: I did check that I connected it properly and it appears that I do have it connected.  Is there a way to double check?

Comment: NSString *rowJunk = [crazyStuff numberOfRows];
returns Null every time

Comment: NSLog(@"crazyStuff: %@", crazyStuff);

Comment: @ondmike NSLog(@"crazyStuff: %@", crazyStuff); returns null

Comment: Then crazyStuff is not connected to your NSTableView and reloadData has no effect in updateServerList.

Comment: @ondmike The controller MyViewController has the outlet crazyStuff connected to the table view.  Is there anything else that I need to connect? I have tried with and without delegation as well.

Comment: When you say that MyViewController has the outlet crazyStuff connected to the table view, how are you determining this? From looking at the nib/xib in IB? Because clearly, in the code at run-time, crazyStuff is not connected to anything (value is nil).

Comment: One of the most common mistakes when dealing with nibs is to create an object in your code that loads the nib (MyViewController, in this case) and is thus "File Owner", and to create a separate object in your nib (MyViewController) where you actually connect the outlets. Might want to check for that, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @ondmike I think that you were right with your last comment.  crazyStuff is the only table in this project (thus far) so I created a nib specifically to be controlled by MyViewController and connected crazyStuff to a table in that nib.  Now the question that I have is how to activate that window.

Comment: So crazyStuff is an IBOutlet in MyViewController, MyViewController is the File's Owner in the nib, there is no MyViewController object in the nib file itself (File's Owner is a proxy to the actual owner object that does not reside in the nib), and when you select File's Owner in the nib and select the Connections inspector you see that crazyStuff is connected to your table view?

Comment: If all of the above is correct, then how are you creating your MyViewController and loading it's nib file?

Comment: @ondmike  I really appreciate all of the help.  I have everything connected as you mention above.  This is a core data project and so I execute this:  [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self]; in the MyDocument.m .   I've been teaching myself this stuff (probably not the best way) so I'm guessing the way I'm loading MyViewController isn't right.

Comment: If "self" is MyDocument, then MyDocument is the actual File's Owner when the nib is loaded. If your nib is indeed set up as detailed above, with File's Owner set as MyViewController, then there is your problem (there is no crazyStuff outlet available to connect to when the nib is loaded). Resolve the mismatch.

Comment: @ondmike  PROGRESS!!!!  crazyStuff: <NSTableView: 0x10055be40>
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
I'll start looking for ways to load the nib

Answer (score 0):

Within `updateServerList` you should `[crazyStuff noteNumberOfRowsChanged]`.  I thought `reloadData` causes the table to re-ask its `dataSource` for the `numberOfRowsInTableView:`, though...

Comment: I tried [crazyStuff noteNumberOfRowsChanged], sadly nothing changed

Comment: Have you double-checked that the NSTableView outlet is connected correectly?