# Setting up NSTableView with NSMutableArray of custom classes as data source

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Alright, so I'm learning programming in Objective-C and Cocoa, and I've run into a problem in the project I'm working on.  So in my code, I have a NSMutableArray (sources) of objects of a custom class.  Each object has a NSString name.  I'm trying to get a table view to display all the objects in sources, by the name of each object.

I have the app delegate class following the NSTableViewDataSource protocol, which means having an objectValueForTableColumn method, and a numberOfRowsInTableView method.

In numberOfRowsInTableView, I just have a return [sources count]; statement, and it works fine.

In objectValueForTableColumn, I have return [[sources objectAtIndex: rowIndex] name];, but nothing is displayed.

I have added a lot of NSLog statements for debugging, and I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know why, or how to fix it.

So, inside `objectValueForTableColumn`, the sources array is nil.  Inside, `numberOfRowsInTableView`, sources is active, and that method works fine.  Now, both these methods run many times, and every time, sources is active in `numberOfRowsInTableView`, but nil in `objectValueForTableColumn`.

I replaced the return statement in `objectValueForTableColumn` with return @"Test string.";, and it displays the correct number of rows in the table view.  Because of this, I know that the table view is set up correctly, besides the problem I am having with sources.

I can't figure out why sources works in one method, but not the other.  I also haven't found a solution to get my table view working correctly.  Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

edit:

```
- (void) loadFromFile
{
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/alex/opt/Wallify.plist";
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath])
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData new] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
    NSLog(@"Loaded data from file.");


    self.sources = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
    [data release];

    for ( ATImageSource *i in sources)
    {
        NSLog(@"retaining i");
        [i retain];
    }



    [sources retain];


    NSLog(@"&imgsrc: %p", sources);
    NSLog(@"imgsrc: %@", sources);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@",[[sources objectAtIndex: 0] name]);

}
else
{
    //  Saved settings file does not exist
    //  Load defaults

    self.sources = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: nil];
    [self.sources retain];

    // new code to setup testfoldersrc
    ATFolderSource *f = [ATFolderSource new];
    f.name = @"Documents";
    f.source = @"/Users/alex/Documents/";
    f.localPath = @"/Users/alex/Documents/";
    f.type = @"f";

    [f populateArrayFromLocalPath];

    [self.sources addObject: f];
    [f release];

    // new code to setup testrsssrc
    ATRSSSource *r = [ATRSSSource new];
    r.name = @"NASA Large Image of the Day";
    r.source = @"http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss";
    r.localPath = @"/Users/alex/opt/nasa_lg_image_of_the_day/";
    r.type = @"r";

    [r getImagesFromRSS];
    [r populateArrayFromLocalPath];

    [self.sources addObject: r];
    [r release];
}

 }
```

Comment: How about setting a breakpoint on the [[sources objectAtIndex: rowIndex] name] line, see what sources is when it breaks. I would also NSLog what the result of that line.

Comment: Inside objectValueForTableColumn, sources is always null, so [[sources objectAtIndex: rowIndex] name] is also null.  I have a NSLog inside this method, which shows the value of sources and of [[sources ...] name].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a race condition in which the array is not populated correctly before `NSTableView` requests the display data, or something is messing with it in the meantime.

At any rate, there is probably a better way to do this using an `NSArrayController`. Apple has a detailed tutorial that can even do sub-arrays of the array (Master/Detail views). It's mostly some point and click work, and maybe as advanced as an override or two. Check it out at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html.

Using this method should also provide things like sorting and filtering for free, as well as easier maintenance (depending on your viewpoint).

Comment: I'll definitely look into this.  I do know that the array is fully populated before the tableview requests it.  The array is loaded on program launch, and then it displays to a textfield that the program has loaded.  I then click on a button, and it opens a new window which has the tableview.

Also, I've noticed that as I select the window, and move it around, both methods get called many times.  objectValueForTableColumn always shows null for the array.  Most of the time numberOfRowsInTable shows the correct sources array, but sometimes it shows null instead.

Comment: I can think of two reasons an object will sometimes show as nil and sometimes not... 1) You have it defined in two different places, for example a nib file and then also in code (which `sources` can randomly be either). Or, 2) it's not being retained properly when allocated. Post your initialization code, and the property declaration from the .h file (if relevant). To test #1, you can check the `retainCount`, it may illuminate something.

Comment: Also, be sure that you're going through your accessor methods when you're messing with non-local variables. For example, instead of just saying `value = 10`, do `[self setValue:10]' or `self.value = 10`. This ensures you're accessing the exact property you think you are.

Comment: Ok, so the first line in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method is [self loadFromFile].  This method loads sources from a file, or creates a default sources object if the file does not exist.  I'll post loadFromFile up in my first post.

Comment: Ok, so I started messing around with the Settings.xib file in Interface Builder, and that changed the output a lot, so I think the problem might be in there.  Right now I have the 'Table View (Name)' linked to the tableView object in the app delegate file.  This gives me different output than I had before.  After making that change, numberOfRowsInTableView runs multiple times, and every time it runs, the sources array is set properly.  But, objectValueForTableColumn never runs, so the table view is empty.

Comment: When I have 'Table View (Name)' linked to tableView, and the dataSource linked to the app delegate, I get the problem with having sources sometimes set, sometimes not.  When I have just the dataSource set, I get the same problem with sources.

Comment: I wonder if the `numberOfRowsInTableView` gets called before the load code runs, and thus returns 0. Then, this would mean it would never request the `objectValueForTableColumn`. Have you tried forcing it to reload data using `[tableView reloadData]`? Maybe map it to a button to see if that shows different behavior.

Comment: Also, it will not call `objectValueForTableColumn` if there are no columns. Have you created some [NSTableColumn](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableColumn_Class/) instances and [added them to the table view](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/addTableColumn:)?

Comment: Well, right now, I have a return 1; statement in numberOfRowsInTableView.  I have 1 column in the tableview, but I'm not doing anything with it in the code, I just created it in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally got it, although I'm not entirely sure I understand it yet.  You were right, in that it had something to do with sources being declared too many times, or something along those lines.

To get it to work, I needed to change [self sources] to [[NSApp delegate] sources].  I believe this makes sure that the correct sources object is being accessed.  I realize that this is probably bad coding practice, and most of the tutorials suggest using a Singleton class instead, but this works for now and I'll clean it up later.

I'm not sure if the changes I made to the xib file made a difference.  I have the app delegate linked to the table view as tableView, delegate, and dataSource.  For some reason, [self sources] inside the objectValueForTableColumn does not reference the same sources object as [self sources] every other method, even though all of them are in the app delegate object.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! I have a feeling it has something to do with the File Owner and such. A singleton would indeed fix it correctly, or re-arranging the way the application works. For example, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137213/nstableview-not-updating-like-i-think-it-should/5137282#5137282), and particularly comment #9.